# Capture json response value in karate api

Tags: karate, jsonparser

How can I retrieve numeric value from json response in Karate API?

Here I want to retrieve 41651625424 this value in a variable as I have to pass this as input in another request body

```
{"items":{'41651625424': {itemCore: {partNumber: '1234567', productTitle: 'Karate API Testing'}}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. The trick is to convert this to a Java `Map` and then you have a lot of useful methods that do what you want:

```
* def response = {"items":{'41651625424': {itemCore: {partNumber: '1234567', productTitle: 'Karate API Testing'}}}}
* def map = karate.toBean(response.items, 'java.util.LinkedHashMap')
* def first = map.keySet().iterator().next()
* match first == '41651625424'
```